# python manage.py migration not working and so does runserver

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7

I manage to successfully install mysql. But when I try to run following command 
-python manage.py makemigrations
-python manage.py syncdb
It gave me this error.

> import error: no module named python.settings

My wsgi.py file contains

> import os
>
> from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
>
> os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Portfolio.settings")
>
> application = get_wsgi_application()

P.S:I am working on ubuntu 14.04, in addition there is same error in python manage.py runserver command.

Answer (score 3):

I am running a similar server setup (Ubuntu 14.04, Apache, mod_wsgi) and in our wsgi.py file we had to do two things to make sure it worked. We used an import of the top level app directory, and also had a multi-file (not django default) settings structure and had to adjust the specification of our settings file.

For example, our folder structure is:

```
project-directory
- manage.py
- static
- app1-directory
   - settings # a directory, not a file
       - development.py
       - quality_assurance.py
       - production.py
   - wsgi.py
- app2-directory
```

in the wsgi.py file we needed to include this directive immediately before the setdefault line:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
```

The second change that we made was to specify the exact settings file, so instead of "app1-directory.settings" we use this as an example:

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "app-name.settings.quality_assurance")
```

Comment: It looks like your problem may also potentially be due to a namespace collision: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367577/django-shell-no-module-named-settings