# Django: no module named settings

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

When I try to run python manage.py runserver I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/user/lokvi/lokvi_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/user/lokvi/lokvi_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Users/user/lokvi/lokvi_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/user/lokvi/lokvi_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Users/user/lokvi/lokvi_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named settings
```

I have python 2.7 in my virtualenv. I noticed strange thing at the last lines of my stack trace, the line before the last line has path that goes like that: `/lokvi_env/lib/python2.7` etc

But the last line goes like that `System/Library/Frameworks` etc, so it seems like path has changed from virtualenv to system. Is it ok?

Comment: seems there is a path mismatch.. are you using windows?

Comment: @MohideenibnMohammed, mac os

Comment: did you activate your virtualenv?

Comment: @BearBrown, yes

Comment: try `from django.conf import settings`

Comment: yes but ./manage.py shell and then try above comamnd

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Shell No module named settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367577/django-shell-no-module-named-settings)

Answer (score 3):

You need to import `settings` module

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Answer (score 1):

Oh, It was not the python path specific question, sorry. I just needed `__init__.py` in settings module inside of my project, since there were no settings it tried to find it in python lib itself and couldn't, I believe.